# How to get and process data from multiple AsyncValue simultaneusly

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm making an app with offline auto login feature. I have 3 providers that all of them are returning `AsyncValue`, with `providerBoxUserStream` is for returning a User data, `providerAPIUser` for user API, and `providerRepoUser` for user data from database (Hive Flutter). The logic of this screen are:

1. to check is there any User data saved in Hive, then load the data, if exist.
2. then do verification to API backend, if connected to internet/server. If verification is succeeded, go to dashboard page
3. If there's no connection available, it'll only load the user data and then go to dashboard page.

#### edit

The problem is `toPageProcess()` never be executed, eventhough `log(data.toJson())` is executed.

I appreciate any help and advice from you. Thank you.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
      builder: (context, ref, child) {
        final streamUser = ref.watch(providerBoxUserStream);

        return streamUser.when(
          data: (data) {
            Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () async {
              final repo = await ref.watch(providerRepoUser.future);
              final apiu = await ref.watch(providerAPIUser.future);
              final conn = await ref.watch(providerCheckConnectioin);
              // log(data.toJson());
              toPageProcess(user: data, apiu: apiu, repo: repo, conn: conn);
            });
            return splashView();
          },
          error: (error, stackTrace) => splashView(),
          loading: () => splashView(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  toPageProcess(
      {required APIUser apiu,
      required RepositoriUser repo,
      required User user,
      required bool conn}) async {
    // ...
    // move to dashboard page
  }

  splashView() => Container(
        child: const Center(
          child: Icon(Icons.abc),
        ),
      );
```

providers

```dart
final providerBoxUserStream = StreamProvider.autoDispose<User>((ref) async* {
  RepositoriUser repo = await ref.watch(providerRepoUser.future);
  yield* Stream.value((await repo.ambilDataPengguna())!);
  yield (await repo.ambilDataPengguna())!;
});

final providerAPIUser =
    FutureProvider.autoDispose<APIUser>((ref) async => APIUser());

final providerRepoUser =
    FutureProvider.autoDispose<RepositoriUser>((ref) async {
  Box<User> box = await ref.watch(providerBoxUser.future);
  return RepositoriUser(box);
});
```

### EDIT

- change the code to be more clear (providers)
- added the detail about my problem